# ajax call to delete a server file returns html of current page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to use a click to delete `eror_log` file on server
In the code below why I'm getting html of currently viewing page as a response?
This happens regardles `error_log` exists or not
I'm expecting empty string as a response

```
$('.btnmoto').on('contextmenu', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('aa.php', {fn: 'del_erlog'}, function(data){
        console.log(data);  // html of current page
    });
});
```

**aa.php**

```php
function del_erlog(){
    if (is_file('error_log')) {
        unlink('error_log');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the code below why I'm getting html of currently viewing page as a response?

Because that is what the PHP is outputting.

---

I *assume* that somewhere in the PHP you have some code along the lines of

```
if ($_POST['fn'] === 'del_erlog') {
    del_erlog();
}
```

But that doesn't stop the rest of the code in the file running.

You would need an `exit` statement or similar to do that.

(I don't recommend mixing Ajax handling code and HTML document generating code in the same file though, it makes things harder to manage in general).

Comment: `...but that doesn't stop the rest of the code in the file running` - where is that `rest of code`  ? My code is to delete a file and nothing to return. In all other cases - I'm getting empty string in console ?

Comment: The rest of the code in aa.php that you didn't include in the question. (I had to make some assumptions, you didn't provide a [mcve])

Comment: ok, I'll check, thanks a lot